# how can I used tf.argmax in multi-dimensions tensor?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, convolution

I want to know who can I use the ***tf.argmax*** in *multi-dimension tensor* in the Tensorflow using convolution neural network.

bellow is simple example to explain what I want exactly::

**1-D tensor example::**

```
a = [0,1,2,3]
logit_a = tf.one_hot(indices = a, depth = 4)
out_a = tf.argmax(logit_a)
```

the **out_a** will be like this [0,1,2,3]

**2-D tensor example::**

```
b = [[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]]
logit_b = tf.one_hot(indices = b, depth = 8)
out_b = tf.argmax(logit_b)
```

**out_b** will give me this::

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

but what I want is [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] or [[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]]

how can I do that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not specifying the axis that you want to convert your tensor into a one hot tensor vector with so it's defaulting to looking at all elements at once, making logic_b of shape (2, 4, 8) when really what you want it to be is of shape (8, 2, 4). See below:

```
session = tf.InteractiveSession()
a = tf.constant([0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7])
logit_b = tf.one_hot(a, depth = 8, axis = 0)
out_b = tf.argmax(logit_b, axis = 0)
out_b.eval()

#array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
#       [4, 5, 6, 7]])
```